# Why does method require a return value after statement which is always return true?

Tags: java, if-statement

Why does this method (test) need a return value (it is always true)?

```
public boolean test() { //This method must return a result of type boolean
    if (true) {
       return true; // always return true
    }
}
```

and when I added return value, it warns as ***"Dead code"***. So, why don't accept first `test()` method

```
public boolean test(int i) {
   if (true) {
      return true;
    } else { //Dead code
      return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: If a statement is always going to be true, can't you just remove the statement altogether?

Comment: it is just test. I don't have any method that always return true :)

Comment: So it's not always going to be true, so there is more than one path through the code so you need a return statement for each path

Comment: It might be helpful to indicate which Java compiler you are using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method return analysis does not analyse the `if` condition to see if it is always true or false, as generally it wouldn't be a compile-time constant (else you wouldn't be writing an `if` in the first place). It simply sees that there is an `if` that could or could not be taken, and if it is not taken then the method does not return a value, hence the error.

The dead code analysis is done in a separate pass to the method return analysis, which does some more in-depth analysis that looks inside branch conditions.

My completely uninformed guess is this behaviour is an artefact of how the compiler was developed; method return analysis is a vital part of compilation, to ensure you get a valid program out at the end, and so was one of the core features implemented first. Dead code analysis is a 'nice to have' and so was implemented later on, using more sophisticated algorithms (as the core compiler bits were finished by that stage)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that compiler won't evaluate if conditions

Answer (score 2):

It is a result of the depth of analysis the compiler does.

Answer (score 1):

This method doesn't do anything, so yeah, it is dead code. If the method always return true, you don't need to call it, just use `true` instead.

Comment: it is just test. I don't have any method that always return true :)

Comment: @hilal, The compiler tries to detect common bugs, it doesn't try to handle all possible theoretical cases and try to deduce what you might want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, if you specify a return type (boolean) you must explicitly specify the value, regardless of whether it's always the same. That does raise the question: if it's always the same, why return anything? You already know the answer in the calling code.

Why not just write:

```
public boolean test() {
  return true;
}
```

As for the second part of your question, the compiler sees that the second path is never taken in the if statement and gives you a warning about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you test something, it may be a value or another value. So you can't guarantee that is going to get inside the if statement.

```
if (someBoolean){
  return true;
}
```

won't work cause someBoolean can be either true or false.
If your method must return something and someBoolean is false, it will not return anything.
So in this case, you can do:

```
if (someBoolean){
  return true;
}
```

return false;

or simply

```
return someBoolean;
```